# About posting data in a client component with Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

To send asynchronous requests from a client component, it seems possible to use the use hook and cache　like below.

```
"use client";

const getTest = cache(async (): Promise<Test[]> => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/test");
  return await response.json();
});

const Input: FC = () => {
  const testList: Test[] = use(getTest());
```

However, the use hook shouldn't be callable from within custom methods. In order to push the return value from the function below into the testList as a response to a button click event, what would be a good approach?

```
const postTest = async (request: Omit<Test, "id">): Promise<Test> => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/test", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
    });
    return await response.json();
  };
```

One possible solution is to execute `const testList: Test[] = use(getTest());` within the server component and use `router.refresh()` in the button's click event. Are there any other good approaches?

If anyone has knowledge about this, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.